# How do I set the flow rate on my Ender 3 Pro and have it stay at that percentage?

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware

I am trying to increase the flow rate on my Ender 3 from 100 to 108 % but every time I start a new print it reverts back to the old 100 % flow rate. I have clicked through the settings and pressed the "store settings" button but it still reverts back at the start of every print. I don't want to do this in my slicer settings as I run 18 Ender 3's so I want to be able to use the same G-code for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the **flow rate** during a print can **not** be saved. There simply is no way. It is usually meant to be a fix with filament inconsistencies or to look for the right extrusion factor for a new filament batch.

### Slicer

The only way to consistently increase the flow rate would be  to alter the `flow rate` in your slicer to what you have found to work best for each machine, probably using separate profiles. This will up the rate for every subsequently sliced print. Note though that this 108 % increased extrusion is converted extrusion factors that are simply numerical and 1.08 times the normal in the g-code. These numerical values will be taken as 100 % by the printer - and since it requires extra work to slice the gode for different profiles it is not the optimal solution.

As you elaborated though, this is not a doable thing, so let's look further.

### Source hunt & Workaround

Since only one printer is showing underextrusion while the others do not, it is time to check the hard- and firmware:

- underextrusion can be caused by a defective extruder assembly or a damaged or blocked nozzle.
- if a machine has consistent underextrusion, its steps/mm in the firmware might be off. This could be altered and stored in the EEPROM. Since this could be a machine unique setting, here would be your point of attack to increase the extrusion of just one machine while using the identical G-code to all other machines.

Note that the standard firmware of the Ender-3 in 2019 did not contain Thermal Runaway Protection ([What is Thermal Runaway Protection?](/q/8466/)) and should be upgraded because of this anyway. You have to flash a bootloader too, so in the process of doing the upgradeability and safety-upgrade to all the machines, you could store the altered steps/mm to each machine individually so they get consistent output.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a global override to the flow percentage on Marlin firmware printers.

Add this line somewhere in your start code:

`M221 S97 ; Flow Percentage hard set.`

In Cura, edit the printer's machine settings. The `S` is the percentage. In my case, 97 % works for PLA+.

Here is a link you might find useful.
[Marlin Docs](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M221.html)